# Finding integral surface from a partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given PDE is
$$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+(u-x-y)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=x+2y$$
Find integral surface which also passes through $u=1+y$ on $x=1$.

I used Lagrange's Auxiliary equations & found
$$\frac{x+y+u}x=A, \frac{x+y+u}{y+u}=B$$
I got $A$ & $B$ relation as $B = \dfrac A{A-1}$ by using curve given.

While finding last integral equation (by substituting $A$ & $B$ expressions) I am unable to get an integral surface. Instead I am getting $1 = 1$.

Please tell me, where am I making mistake?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ Dvaavimshathihi. You did a good work on the way to solve the problem. Your two characteristic equations are both correct but unfortunately they are not undependent one to the other. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two characteristic equations that you found are correct. This is a good start.
$$\frac{x+y+u}{x} = A$$
$$\frac{x+y+u}{y+u} = B$$
The hitch is that they are not undependent because
$$\frac{y+u}{x}=\frac{A}{B}=A-1$$
Of course one can keep the simplest characteristic equation
$$\frac{y+u}{x}=c_1$$
But one have to find another undependent characteristic equation from the Charpit-Lagrange ODEs.
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{u-x-y}=\frac{du}{x+2y}$$
$u=c_1x-y\quad\implies\quad \frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{(c_1x-y)-x-y}\quad\implies\quad \frac{dy}{dx}=c_1-1-\frac{2y}{x}$

Solving this first order linear ODE leads to $y=\frac{c_1-1}{3}x+\frac{c_2}{x^2}$

A second characteristic equation is $y=\frac{\frac{y+u}{x}-1}{3}x+\frac{c_2}{x^2}$ and after simplification with $c_3=-2c_2$ :
$$u=2y+x+\frac{c_3}{x^2}$$

The general solution of the PDE on implicit form is :
$$u(x,y)=2y+x+\frac{1}{x^2}F\left( \frac{y+u}{x}\right)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function to be determined according to the condition $u(1,y)=y+1$.

I suppose that you can do it. My result is :

$$u(x,y)=\frac{x-y+2x^3(2y+x)}{2x^3+1}$$
This is the particular solution which satisfies both the PDE and the condition. To be checked.